# How to make two or more REST calls for a single component in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, http, react-native

I am developing a page that requires data from different REST calls. Being new to reactjs i am not getting examples on how to make multiple REST calls for a single component.

Comment: Share some code.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: need to make more than one GET REST calls for single page (componentDidMount()).

Comment: I came across promise.all this seems to be the solution for my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can make multiple API calls in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method of the said component.

A beautiful way to achieve this would be to use `async/await` to help make your code look synchronous whilst being asynchronous and when you get the result, call `setState` so that your render function can have the chance to re-render and get the new data you have fetched.

Example:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const callOne = await fetch.....
    const callTwo = await fetch.....
    this.setState({ ... results of callOne });
    this.setState({ ...results of callTwo });
}
```

Comment: Can you share an example on this.